# MongoDB schema: Like a Comment OR a Post

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to setup a "like" system in my app. User should be able to like either Posts or Comments (Comments of a Post of course). How should I design this?

**Users**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: String, required: true },
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

**Posts**

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true }
});
```

**Comments**

```
const commentSchema = new Schema({
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    postId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post", required: true },
});
```

**Likes**

```
const likeSchema = new Schema({
    content: { type: String, required: false },
    authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    postId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post", required: function() { return this.commentId? false : true } },
    commentId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment", required: function() { return this.postId? false : true } }
});
```

I'm coming from relational databases, and maybe my design is completely wrong for nosql. My main interrogation is about Likes, I have no idea how to accept likes on Posts OR Comments.

Comment: Why not comment embedded in post?

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer a separate collection:

```
User:
    id:  
    ...

Post:
    id:
    userId:
    ...

Comment:
    id:
    userId:
    postId:

Like:
    id:
    userId:
    postId:
    commentId:
```

The second one storing an array will lead you cyclic dependencies in the backend. Especially, when you use NodeJS and strict to flow.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is powerful at storing documents. Documents hold the relations.
I would model it in the way your data is being accessed. I do recommend playing around with the powerful aggregation framework and array operators to experience the possibilities. What I would explore is the following

```
User:
  id: 
  name:
  picture:
  ...

Posts:
  id: 
  authorid:
  content:
  total_views:
  tags: array of String
  likes: array of Likes {[
         liked_by: user_id
     ],...}
  comments: array of Comments {[
     author_id: ...
     comment: ...
     reactions: array of Comments {[],...}
     likes: array of Likes {[
         liked_by: user_id
          ],...}
      ],...}
```

Will this model scale? Documents can hold 16MB of data. 16MB in textual format is HUGE.

PS please think again on storing username/password in the database. This is a whole other discussion. Look into the topics of authentication, authorisation, OAuth, hashing/salting etc.

Comment: Of course I'm gonna use hashing/salting before storing password in the database =) It's just a simplified version for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
post={
 ...keys,
 likes:[likeSchema],
 comments:[CommentSchema]
}
```

this is i prefer, even if you want to store recursive comments just use

```
commentschema={
 id:unique commet id
 text:...
 user_id:who wrote this comment
 parent_id: to which this comment belongs to!
 depth: comment depth as your wish (mostly 2)
}
```

parent id will be null for a comment posted directly on post
parent id will be comment_id of the comment to which this comment posted for. if its a recursive comment.

hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the question is about schema for like a comment or post. I'll focus on likes.

Build a schema like this. Here targetId will be **postId or commentId**.

```
const likeSchema = new Schema({
    content: { type: String, required: false },
    authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    targetId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post", required: function() { return this.commentId? false : true } }
});
```

Some points you need to consider:

1. Store likes of posts in post collection
2. Store likes of comments in comments collection
3. You need to build a mechanism to calculate likes and store in that collection